# Как выполнить код, записанный в массиве String

Tags: java

Мне нужно чтобы программа выполняла код, записанный в массиве строк. Допустим:

```
String TEST_STRING = "System.out.println(\"Мама мыла раму\");";
String[] testString = new String[2];
testString[0] = TEST_STRING;
//Здесь каким-то образом выполняется код, записанный в testString[0]
```

Comment: код на java? в вашем примере, код не корректный с точки зрения java.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а почему код не корректный?

Comment: @D. Karev  наверное, вам сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code

Comment: вам нужно добавть класс и метод `main`.

Comment: гуглите Java Compiler API

Comment: вы не ответили - код обязательно должен быть на java? или вам просто нужно иметь возможность выполнить код (например JavaScript)?

Comment: Класс и метод есть - я не стал их писать, дабы не захломлять вопрос. Код должен быть на Java

Answer (score 0):

разъясните подробнее постановку задачи, может быть вам и не нужно такое вульгарное решение.
От себя советую познакомиться с паттерном "команда". Вот к примеру реализация "пульта управления".

1) У нас есть некоторый набор сущностей с которыми надо взаимодействовать, они могут выполнять действие откатывать его и сообщать свой статус

```
public class SomeEntity{

private boolean status = false;

public void do() {
    this.status = false;
    //do your code
}

public void undo() {
    this.status = true;
    //undo your code
}

public boolean getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}
}
```

2)Теперь мы пишем команду для каждого сценария нашего класса

```
public interface Command {

public void execute();

public void undo();
}
```

3)За командой прикрепляется сущность с которой она взаимодействует

```
public class MyCommand implements Command {

private final SomeEntity someEntity;

public MyCommand (SomeEntity someEntity) {
    this.someEntity= someEntity;
}

@Override
public void execute() {
    this.someEntity.do();
}

@Override
public void undo() {
    this.someEntity.undo();
}
}
```

4)а теперь создадим пульт, который бы знал в лицо объекты с которыми ему взаимодействовать и научим его выполнять макросы

```
public class Controller {

private final ArrayList<Command> сommands;

public Controller() {
    this.сommands = new ArrayList<Command>();
}

public void addCommand(Command сommand) {
    this.сommands.add(сommand);
}

public void executeCommand(int index) {
    if (index < this.сommands.size()) {
        this.сommands.get(index).execute();
    }else{
        new DoNothingCommand().execute();
        //comand which doing nothing
    }
}

public void undoCommand(int index) {
    if (index < this.undoCommands.size()) {
        this.commands.get(index).undo();
    }else{
        new DoNothingCommand().execute();
    }
}
}
```

а теперь подумайте сколько всего прикольного можно сделать, вы можете циклом обойти весь список в `commands` и вызвать их `execute()` - вот вам и макрос на уровне пульта.
Или ещё круче сделать набор макросов на уровне команд: создать `Command` в котором лежал бы такой-же `ArrayList<Command>` и `execute()` который бы их все выполнял. Тогда пульт даже не знает, что внутри одной из его команд лежит целый сценарий, он выполняет всего один `execute()` и забывает про это.

5) работа с пультом

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controller myController = new Controller();
    SomeEntry someEnttity = new SomeEntity ();
    //create as much entities as you want...
    myController.addCommand(new SomeCommand(someEntry));
    //Appoint comands for your entities and add them to controller...
    myController.executeCommand(0);
    //press an button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще примитивный пример принта в консоль используя [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/), но не уверен что это именно то, что вам нужно, думаю в вашем случае скорее Java Compiler API

```
    ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine js = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("js");
    try {
         js.eval("print(\"someText\")");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```